# How to delete a file

Tags: android

I am working on a small app where you can send an email with a file attachment. When the email is sent, the file has to be deleted. I start the email intent using `startActivityForResult(emailIntent)` and catch the response in `onActivityResult()`. The problem is that onActionResult() is called immediately after I press send button in the email client, not when the email has actually been sent. I also read that `ACTION_SEND` is not designed for you with `startActivityForResult()`. So the question is when/how to delete the file? I was thinking that I can run a `Thread`, that will check whether the file is not used by any other process and then, delete it. The problem might be when the application is destroyed, the thread is destroyed and the file will not ever be deleted. So what about running some kind of `Service` that will wait until file can be deleted and then kill itself.
What would be the best solution?

Comment: deleteOnExit() - Schedules this file to be automatically deleted when the VM terminates normally. So when the file should actually be deleted?

Note that on Android, the application lifecycle does not include VM termination, so calling this method will not ensure that files are deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the email is sent, the file has to be deleted.

That will not be readily possible, as you have no way of knowing when the file is sent.

> I start the email intent using startActivityForResult(emailIntent) and catch the response in onActivityResult().

`ACTION_SEND` is not designed for use with `startActivityForResult()`, and even if it were, there is no guarantee that when `onActivityResult()` is called that the email has actually been sent. You have no way of knowing if the email has been sent. For example, the email client may have simply queued the email to be sent, because there is no Internet connection, or the email's settings are set such that it sends emails in batches, or whatever.

> So the question is when/how to delete the file?

Wait 24 hours, then delete it, and hope the email was sent in that period of time.

> I was thinking that I can run a Thread, that will check whether the file is not used by any other process and then, delete it.

You are making assumptions about the implementations of the other apps. There is no requirement that a third-party email app has to have your file opened when you happen to think that it should be opened.

> So what about running some kind of Service that will wait until file can be deleted and then kill itself.

Again, you have no way to really know when the file can be deleted. 24 hours is a guess; it is conceivable that the email might still be queued, and the other app might still need the attachment. However, a time-based policy is the least-invalid assumption that you can make, and it also makes it a bit easier for users to perhaps configure how long to let the file linger before you delete it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But lets suppose that the file is a picture taken from a custom camera and its only purpose is to be "alive" until it is sent and based on the requirements, it must be deleted. The only option which looks convenient, as you said, is to delete the file after 24 hours+- and hope, that it has been sent. What if the phone is turned of within those 24 hours? I guess the email is deleted from the queue and is never intended to be sent again, but the image persist there.

Comment: @Husky: "What if the phone is turned of within those 24 hours? I guess the email is deleted from the queue and is never intended to be sent again, but the image persist there" -- since the phone is off, nobody should care, and there is nothing you can do about it anyway, as the phone is off and your code cannot run. You are welcome to use `AlarmManager` to trigger the deletion process, and you are welcome to check for files to be deleted on boot as well (to cover the "turned off" scenario).

Comment: @Husky: Moreover, your "requirements" will probably dictate that you cannot use `startActivity()` to send the email. Instead, you will need to upload the file to your server and send it from there, or you will need to use JavaMail (or the equivalent) to send it directly yourself. `ACTION_SEND` and `ACTION_SENDTO` are for more casual use and may not necessarily meet all "requirements".